# How to create an excel file that won't be locked for editing when others open it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, read-only, shared-access, locked-files

I have a file that I'd like others (potentially a dozen+) to have access to at all times, but that I can also edit even if others have it open. If I make it so it requests the user open it as Read Only, and assuming they do so, would that still allow me to edit the file if they have it open as Read Only?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with file based access do you have SharePoint? If it's a public document consider using Google Docs.

Comment: Our group doesn't typically use Sharepoint but maybe that is an option if I can't figure something out. And no not a public document. We mostly use file based access for 99% of items.

What about having two files; the one the other users open, and one that I put raw data into. Then the user runs a script to import the data over? Although I guess more than 1 person wouldn't be able to open/run the macro at the same time...

Comment: Your situation is just bad fit for the tool you're using. Depending on what is in the document a database would be a better tool with a suitable frontend.

Comment: It's not possible with Excel.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe be able to use one of the other `Protect Workbook` options, but I do a different route: I go out to the directory and right-click-> properties and (un)check the read-only attribute.

[image]

In excel it looks like this:

[image]
To have success with read only on sharepoint, you have to checkout the file (I'm too lazy to find the stack exchange reference).